# Perl Module to convert numbers to letter notation

Tags: perl, perl-module

Is there a perl module that will convert a number to a letter and vice versa?

For instance

```
1 = A 
2 = B
3 = C
...
27 = AA
28 = AB
29 = AC
...
53 = BA
54 = BB
55 = BC
```

So on and so forth.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code shows a function `a2n` that does what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;

printf "%2s = %d\n", $_, a2n($_) for qw/ A B C AA AB AC BA BB BC /;

sub a2n {
  my $n = 0;
  $n = $n * 26 + $_ for map { ord($_) & 0x1F } split //, shift;
  $n;
}
```

**output**

```
 A = 1
 B = 2
 C = 3
AA = 27
AB = 28
AC = 29
BA = 53
BB = 54
BC = 55
```

A corresponding `n2a` looks like this

```
sub n2a {
  my ($n) = @_;
  my @a;
  while ($n > 0) {
    unshift @a, ($n-1) % 26;
    $n = int(($n-1)/26); #Edited for failing corner case
  }
  join '', map chr(ord('A') + $_), @a;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, Perl can handle letters in ranges, which might suit your needs:

```
my @letters = 'A' .. 'BC'; # A B C ... Z AA AB AC etc.
```

Then you can simply do:

```
my $letter = $letter[$foo - 1];   # 1 -> A, 2 -> B ...
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a cute trick with the `..` operator. Try:

```
print join ",",("A".."ZZ"),"\n"
```

or

```
my @a = ("A".."ZZ");
print $a[56],"\n";
```

This is not really a good way if you're going to go up into the 100s of thousands of elements, though. Then you're better of doing the maths (very simple maths) for base-26 yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need a module for this?

```
my $n = 55;
my $s = 'A';
$s++ while --$n;
print "$s\n";
```

Comment: but this would break if you do `$s-- while --$n`. You'd end up with `-1`( some negative number) right?

Comment: @chrsblck The auto-decrement operator is not magical, only the increment operator. This is documented in perldoc perlop.

Comment: @chrsblck Well, if you're going to change an operator that works for one that does not, then that's something you could say about a lot of operators. `++` increments letter. `--` does not decrement letters.